# 【Sklearn】Understanding GridSearchCV.best_score_

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

Can anyone give a brief explanation on what `best_score_` means?

I assume the score is higher the better.

Is there a range for the score for example (0,1)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Grid-search is used to find the optimal hyperparameters of a model, which results in the most `accurate` predictions. The grid.best_score gives the best optimal hyperparameters. This is calculated by the average of all the cross-validation fold for a single combination of the parameters you specify in the tuned_params.

Based on best_score_, we can choose the best optimal hyperparameter for the model, giving good accuracy for the model.

Comment: Is there a range for the score for example (0,1)?